TextInput text not vertically centered when using NativeWind class `text-base` or other text classes
I have a TextInput like this:
<TextInput className="text-base" />

But when I input some text, it's not vertically centered:

I think this is because the text-base class also sets the line height since if I do
<TextInput className="text-[20px]" />

it will be centered vertically:

So how can I still use the predefined class names from NativeWind but also have it centered vertically?
